# Mapbox: Programatically update mapbox dataset from .geojson file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapbox, put, mapbox-gl-js

I have a .geojson file (call it data.geojson) which I use to manually update a dataset on mapbox.

Suppose that my data.geojson file is structured as follows:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "suburb": "A",
        "unemployed": 10
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "suburb": "B",
        "unemployed": 20
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          1,
          1
        ]
      }
```

data.geojson is stored locally, and every 12 hours the 'unemployed' property of each feature is updated using another python script that scrapes data from the web.

Currently, in order to update these properties within the online dataset (stored at mapbox.com) I am manually navigating to the Mapbox website and  reuploading the data.geojson file. I am looking for a way to accomplish this task pythonically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried to fetch the data with the [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) package? (given any login credentials you need of course). You may also be interested by the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) lib.

Comment: @s.k I am not sure exactly how I would go about doing that. I am very new to programming for the web. Is there a link you could direct me towards?

Comment: Sure, many; https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-web-apis-in-python-3 & https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/ & https://medium.com/quick-code/absolute-beginners-guide-to-slaying-apis-using-python-7b380dc82236 & https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-pull-data-from-an-api-using-python-requests-edcc8d6441b1 I'm just wondering if your "other script that scrapes data from the web" is already based on these kind of API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the links. In regards to your question about the "other script", the data that I'm scraping is not actually unemployment data, it is more obscure than that and there is no API for it. Subsequently my data scraping script uses Selenium to scrape data directly from a website, and converts it into .geojson format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, in the end, was simply to point the source of the Mapbox layer to the locally stored dataset.geojson file rather than the corresponding dataset stored online at mapbox.com.

I was able to edit the locally stored dataset.geojson using the 'json' python package. Since the Mapbox layer source was pointing directly to the local dataset, all updates to this local file would then be reflected in the Mapbox layer. This way, there is no need to upload any data to Mapbox.

@David also posted a helpful solution if you wish to go down that route.

Answer (score 1):

you can setup a timer of some sort to automatically update the data using javascript functions. Here I am using a source and layer named "STI", which is just geoJSON line data.

The function would first add the source of the data as well as the layer :

```
var STI_SOURCE = 'json/sti/STI.json'; // declare URL for data


        map.addSource('sti', { type: 'geojson', data: STI1 }); // Add source using URL

        // Add the actual layer using the source
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "sti",
            "type": "line",
            "source": "sti",
            "layout": {
                "line-join": "miter",
                "line-cap": "round"
            },
            "paint": {
                "line-color": "#fff",
                "line-width": 1,
                "line-dasharray": [6, 2]
            }
        });
```

Then, when you want to refresh the data - remove them :

```
                    map.removeLayer('sti');       
                    map.removeSource('sti');
```

Then, you can re-add them by starting at the beginning. There are other ways (and better) to do this, but this is just one way that works. I think there is a setData() function that does this better. But hopefully this can get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in the end, I opted to keep the dataset stored locally and simply point the mapbox layer source to the locally stored dataset. I was then able to update the  locally stored dataset pythonically (which is just a .geojson file) using the 'json' python package. This way, no reliance on online datasets is necessary.